# ¿Cómo pueden graficarse datos obtenidos en un bucle?

Tags: r

Con este código (adjunto bibliotecas para quien necesite):

```
library(rcompanion)
library(psych)
library(MASS)
library(nortest)
library(ggplot2)
n <-1e3
LímiteMenorMuestra=20
LímiteMayorMuestra=150
m <- seq(from=LímiteMenorMuestra, to=LímiteMayorMuestra)
te2 <- for(i in m){
  t2err <- 0
  for(j in 1:n){
    x <- rnorm(i, 0, 1)
    if(t.test(x, mu = 0.5)$p.value > 0.05){
      t2err <- t2err + 1
    }
  }
  print(i)
  print(1-(t2err/n))
}
plot(i, (1-t2err/n))
```

se obtienen resultados de error tipo 2 para muestras de 20 a 150.
Y si bien me imprime cada uno de los valores de Error para cada muestra, tales como

```
[1] 20
[1] 0.577
[1] 21
[1] 0.561
[1] 22
[1] 0.589
[1] 23
[1] 0.633
```

A la hora de graficar sólo obtengo el ultimísimo resultado (para i = 150, t2err=1). ¿Alguna forma de hacer que salgan todos y cada uno de los valores de t2err?
Mi gratitud por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ningún momento de la función `for` almacenas los resultados obtenidos en cada una de las corridas, solo los muestras en la consola mediante el comando `print`. Para poder almacenarlos generaremos una matriz `Resultados`, de tamaño 0x2 en la que, en cada paso de las funciones `for`, pondremos el tamaño de muestra y el error (lo mismo que se muestra en los `print`) (`Resultados<-matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 0)`).

Para cada valor de i dentro `for`, adiconaremos una fila con el tamaño muestral y el error de tipo II (`Resultados<-rbind(Resultados, c("n"=i, "ETII"=1-(t2err/n)))`). Debemos poner `Resultados` dentro del `rbind` para que no lo sobreescriba en cada corrida.

Finalmente lo graficamos con la función `plot`.

El código quedaría:

```
n <-1e3
LímiteMenorMuestra=20
LímiteMayorMuestra=150
m <- seq(from=LímiteMenorMuestra, to=LímiteMayorMuestra)
Resultados<-matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 0)
for(i in m){
  t2err <- 0
  for(j in 1:n){
    x <- rnorm(i, 0, 1)
    if(t.test(x, mu = 0.5)$p.value > 0.05){
      t2err <- t2err + 1
    }
  }
  print(i)
  print(1-(t2err/n))
  Resultados<-rbind(Resultados, c("n"=i, "ETII"=1-(t2err/n)))
}

plot(Resultados)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el bucle sólo produce efecto colateral (los `print()`) y no está guardando cada valor de `t2err`. Los bucles no generan un output "verdadero" (i.e. no un side effect) si no les indicamos explícitamente que lo hagan.

Una forma un poco cruda de hacerlo sería:

```
n <-1e3
LímiteMenorMuestra=20
LímiteMayorMuestra=150
m <- seq(from=LímiteMenorMuestra, to=LímiteMayorMuestra)

out <- numeric() #Creo un vector vacío en el que voya ir guardando cada valor de t2err

for(i in m){
  t2err <- 0
  for(j in 1:n){
    x <- rnorm(i, 0, 1)
    if(t.test(x, mu = 0.5)$p.value > 0.05){
      t2err <- t2err + 1
    }
  }
  print(i)

  out[i-LímiteMenorMuestra+1] <- 1-(t2err/n)      #Ajusto el número de índice, ya que i no comienza en 1. out se va llenando con t2err. OJO: asigna, en el entorno global!
  names(out)[i-LímiteMenorMuestra+1] <- paste(i)  #Le asigno nombres cada elemento del vector
}

barplot(out)
```

Genera un barplot con una barra por cada elemento de out y la altura controlada por el valor de out.

> El gráfico indica que la tasa de error del tipo II es **creciente** con el tamaño de muestra. Te sugiero revisar la fórmula que estás usando o aclarar que estás mostrando 1-beta (el ""poder"" estadístico del diseño).

Answer (score 0):

La explicación del problema ya te la han dado en las otras respuestas: no estas persisitiendo los datos que buscas luego de cada iteración. Lo que tengo para agregar y buscaba resolver, es un aproximación a la solución usando `dplyr` y `ggplot`. La base es reproducir los dos ciclos generando un `data.frame` con todos los valores de `i` que vamos a usar:

```
data.frame(i=rep(seq(from=LímiteMenorMuestra, to=LímiteMayorMuestra), each=n))
```

Es decir los valores de 20 a 250 repetidos 1000 veces cada uno. luego simplemente usamos algunos verbos de `dplyr` junto con `map()` para generar el valor final de `t2err`, luego simplemente agrupamos y sumarizamos.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2019)

n <-1000
LímiteMenorMuestra=20
LímiteMayorMuestra=150

df <- data.frame(i=rep(seq(from=LímiteMenorMuestra, to=LímiteMayorMuestra), each=n))
df %>% 
    mutate(p.value = map(i, rnorm, 0, 1) %>%     # rnorm por cada valor de i
                     map(t.test, mu=0.5) %>%     # t.test sobre el valor de rnorm
                     map(`[[`, 'p.value') %>%    # extraemos p.value
                     unlist(),                   
           t2err = ifelse(p.value > 0.5, 1, 0)   # t2err por cada p.value
           ) %>% 
    group_by(i) %>%                              # agrupamos por cada i
    summarise(t2err=1-sum(t2err)/n) %>%          # Calculamos el t2err final de cada i
    ggplot() +
        geom_point(mapping=aes(x=i, y=t2err), shape=1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]